# Find all folders starting with number range

Tags: find, wildcards

How can I find all folders starting with a value in the number range 500 to 899?
I just need to list them in a file.

Additional informations:

- Maxdepth 2
- Examples of folder names: `593091_azerty_qwerty` or `849934_blablablabla_bla_blabla`

Comment: What's the format of the number? Can there be `0502foo`, `5000bar`, `0x200123`, `899.99xxx`, `5e2-qwe`... directories?

Comment: Are you looking at the first three characters of the file name? With your file names, I would have thought that `593091_azerty_qwerty` doesn't match because 593091 is not in the desired range. Should `0555_foo` match?

Answer (score 2):

try this (if your  `find` supports the `-maxdepth` option):

```
find parent_dir -maxdepth 2 -type d \(
  -name '[5-8][0-9][0-9][!0-9]*' -o -name '[5-8][0-9][0-9]' \) > my_file1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, assuming the numbers are always decimal integers (in the range supported natively by your processor):

```
setopt extended_glob
dirs=(<500-899>([^0-9]*|)(/N) */<500-899>([^0-9]*|)(/DN))
```

However note that for the second pattern, if there are symlinks to directories in the current directory, `zsh` will look for `<500-899>...` directory in their target.

Shortened with brace expansion factorisation:

```
dirs=({,*/}<500-899>([^0-9]*|)(/DN))
```

If the numbers are always followed by `_`, you can simplify it to:

```
dirs=({,*/}<500-899>_*(ND))
```

Note with versions of `zsh` prior to 5.2, because of the way integers are represented by the processor, that will match numbers that are between 500 and 899 modulo 2<sup>64</sup>, so for instance would match on `590295810358705652224_something` as that's 2<sup>69</sup> + 512.